# How can I save my Sharepoint list value as currency/decimal?

Tags: c#, casting, sharepoint-2010, decimal, sharepoint-list

I have an item/member of a Sharepoint 2010 list that is declared as data type CUrrency:

```
list.Fields.Add("Section5Total", SPFieldType.Currency, false);
```

Yet, when I try to save a currency value into that member, it won't compile. This:

```
spli["Section5Total"] = (SPFieldCurrency)boxSection5Total.Text;
```

...gives me,

> Cannot convert type 'string' to 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCurrency'

This:

```
spli["Section5Total"] = (decimal)boxSection5Total.Text;
```

...similarly tells me I can't convert `String` to `Decimal`.

I get that the compiler is not going to look at "Section5Total" and figure out that it has been declared as a Currency `SPFieldType`. Yet this:

```
spli["Section5Total"] = 0.0;
```

...compiles just fine. So why does it accept a literal float val, but not a cast one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast a string to decimal.
Try:

```
spli["Section5Total"] = Convert.ToDecimal(boxSection5Total.Text);
```